# Божья коровка

Tags: этимология

Вот, задумалась: а почему, собственно, жук называется "божья коровка"? Никаких ассоциаций с коровой он не вызывает, а почему божья - вообще не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему коровка? -   Если осторожно прикоснуться к этому жуку, то насекомое выделит из сгибов ножек каплю оранжевой жидкости - « молочка». Поэтому и дали ему такое  название . Эта жидкость отпугивает врагов  божьей   коровки . (Из энциклопедии для детей "Что такое? Кто такой?»)
Почему божья? Вот такое мнение есть:  люди издревле заметили, что там, где наблюдается массовое скопление божьих коровок, всегда получается хороший урожай. Видимо, именно по этой причине, этого, ранее неприметного жучка и назвали, «божьим».

Древние славяне считали коровку тем насекомым, которое способно летать к Богу, поэтому стремились передавать ему различные свои просьбы. Конечно, чаще всего, люди просили у нее достатка в доме и любви. В том случае, если коровка после просьб сразу же взлетала, означало, что пожелания услышаны, и она полетела их выполнять.

Несмотря на то, что в разных странах мира это насекомое называется по-разному, общий смысл названий все - же сводится к божественному определению. Так, например, в Германии и Швейцарии, божья коровка называют жуком Святой Девы Марии

Answer (score 0):

По сути - согласен.
Вот только урожай здесь, полагаю, ни при чем.
Божья - здесь того же порядск что и в "Божья роса" или "божий человек".
Абсолютная беззащитность, безобидность и даже ненужность (как полагали) насекомого.

Answer (score 0):

Помню в далёком детстве - если поймаешь "Божью коровку" то сажаешь её на палец и приговариваешь "Божья коровка, улети на небо, принеси мне хлеба. Черного и белого, только не горелого". Во как! А ведь это фольклор.

Comment: Мы говорили "Божья коровка, улети на небо, там твои детки кушают котлетки". Городском вариант! ;-))